# Sending messages to a swing JTextArea from different places

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I have a JTextArea always visible in my main app window (a Log if you like), and I want to use it to display activity going on in the system (like mock-debug output you'd do with System.out.println() in if conditions or whatever)

I mean high level things the user does, (like "successfully loaded file " or " written to disk", " completed" etc)

Thing is such messages can be generated anywhere in my system mainly in another package the classes of which deal with the data and computation, and they're unaware of the GUI.

Maybe save the messages to a temp file and the textarea "monitors" that file for changes, how can this be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way is to define a logger interface:

```
package com.example.logging;
public interface ActivityLogger {
    void logAction(String message);
}
```

Then pass it to your non-GUI components so they don't get tied to a specific implementation:

```
public class FileLoader {

    private ActivityLogger logger;
    public FileLoader(ActivityLogger logger){
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public void loadFile(){
        // load stuff from file
        logger.logAction("File loaded successfully");
    }

}
```

Now, making an implementation that writes to a text component is simple:

```
public class TextComponentLogger implements ActivityLogger{
    private final JTextComponent target;
    public TextComponentLogger(JTextComponent target) {
        this.target = target;
    }

    public void logAction(final String message){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                target.setText(String.format("%s%s%n", 
                                             target.getText(),
                                             message));
            }
        });
    }
}
// Usage:
JTextArea logView = new JTextArea();
TextComponentLogger logger = new TextComponentLogger(logView);
FileLoader fileLoader = new FileLoader(logger);
fileLoader.loadFile();
```

You can of course also use a standard logging framework (java.util.logging, slf4j, log4j, etc) and write an appender that "writes" to a text component.

Answer (score 0):

The design can be rather complicated. Maybe you can have a public access method like updateText() in the class where your TextArea would be. Then you create a kind of 'resource' or 'shared' class (just a plain class) that would be initialized together when your main() runs. When the class containing your TextArea is created, an instance would be placed into the 'shared' class (this shared class should be a singleton) and so all the other classes call this 'shared' class (maybe a method like updateTextArea()) and what it would do is call the class containing the TextArea via that instance and call the TextArea to update text.

Answer (score 0):

The [Message Console](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/08/message-console/) might be what you are looking for.

Java also has a "Logger" API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EventBus](http://eventbus.org/) to decouple your GUI from the other parts of your application.  (My blog has another [introduction](http://developmentality.wordpress.com/2010/05/11/eventbus-introduction-and-troubleshooting-for-annotation-problems/)).  You could do something as follows:

```
public class LogArea extends JTextArea {
    public static final String LOG_TOPIC = "logarea_topic";

    public LogArea() {
        super();
        // Read in the annotations, register self as a listener to the topic
        AnnotationProcessor.process(this);
    }

    @EventTopicSubscriber(topic=LOG_TOPIC)
    public void logEvent(String topic, String text) {
        append(text + "\n");
    }

}

public class DomainClass {

    public void foo() {
        // Send out a notification throughout the system to whichever components
        // are registered to handle this topic.
        EventBus.publish(LogArea.LOG_TOPIC, "some text you want to appear in the log area");
    }

}
```

In a real system you'd probably want to move the topic declarations to another class so that one can use it without being tied to a specific implementation.  E.g. you could have a Topics class that just contains the static string constants of the topics.  Then you can have multiple classes that listen to those topics and process the messages (e.g. you could have a standard logging framework which writes out to a log file in addition to the jtextarea component).