# How to log data to a JTextArea (or JTextPane) from a thread that doesn't have a swing component init?

Tags: java, swing, logging, jtextarea, jtextpane

I have a GUI application that process some data, it converts line of text to an object. Each object that is created is shown on a JTextPane ot JTextArea. example:

Line # 1 created 827401830 
Line # 2 created 827401831

So the user is inform of the process.

Behind the scene, there's a thread that runs in the background and does all the work. The problem is that one of the fields of this thread has is a JTextArea. and it looks like this:

```
public class ConsumerThread implements Runnable 
{
    private ArrayBlockingQueue<TicketExchangeLine> queue;
    private JTextArea textArea; 

public ExchConsumerThread(ArrayBlockingQueue<TicketExchangeLine> queue, JTextArea textArea) 
{
    this.queue = queue;
    this.textArea = textArea; 
}

public void run() 
{
    try
    {       
        while (true)
        {               
            // check if end of file from producer POV
            if (queue.peek()!=null && ...)
                break;

            MyObject obj = queue.take();

            try{
                //do the process here
                textArea.append("here comes the output for the user..."+obj.getID);

            }catch(Exception nfe)
            {
                //Oops  
            } 
        }

        textArea.append("\nDone!");

    }catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        // Oops
    }catch(Exception exp)
    {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

So the code above works fine and does the job but sometimes I'm using this thread not from the GUI and then I'm instantiating a JTextArea for no reason; and even worse, I have to system.out everything to see the process.

Question: how can I log all the 'processed data' to the JTextArea (or sometime JTextPane) without using the Swing components in the thread?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing a `JTextArea`, pass an `OutputStream` (e.g. a `PrintStream`) as parameter. This provides enough flexibility:

- Your thread just writes to the outputstream
- If you want the output to appear in a `JTextArea`, you pass an outputstream which will append the output to a `JTextArea`. The writing to the text area should happen on the EDT, but the outputstream takes care of this. Your thread is unaware of this
- If you want to pipe the output to the `System.out`, you just pass the `System.out` directly as a parameter

Comment: Instead of using an `OutputStream`, you could even use a `Writer`, which deals with characters instead of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Most Swing graphical components are split into a graphical representation (the View) and an abstract representation of the displayed data (the Model). `JTextArea` and `JTextPane` are graphical components that use a `Document` instance as their Models.

So, instead of referencing the `JTextArea` and calling `textArea.append`, you can reference a Document, and call `document.insertString`. Then, if you need to instanciate a JTextArea, use the constructor of JTextArea that takes a Document as an argument (or use its `setDocument` method).

Also, Swing is not thread safe, and every method call that could affect a Swing component should happen in the EDT (the dispatch thread of AWT). To inject some code on the EDT, use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's what you are trying to achieve, but with your current code, you could change the JTextArea on the [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) like this:

```
final MyObject obj = queue.take();
try {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            textArea.append("here comes the output for the user..." + obj.getID);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: but you're still sending a textArea to the thread. My objective is to log the events to a String (log4j) anything that the TextArea can 'listen' to.

Comment: Ahh I'm not sure that something like that exist... I mean with log4j. Is that requirement set in stone? If you have aglobal static log method wouldn't that be enough??

Comment: Hey dude adhg you can setup a custom listener, but you still need to write it to an intermediate location somewhere, but like I said a global static method seems much more cleaner.....

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have already found an answer, but I think this is an elegant and flexible solution to your problem:

[Sending messages to a swing JTextArea from different places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297729/sending-messages-to-a-swing-jtextarea-from-different-places)