# return an ArrayList to swing with logger interface

Tags: java, swing, logging, jtextarea

I'm using the code in this answer to provide logging functionality, and it works well! Thanks gustafc.

[Sending messages to a swing JTextArea from different places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297729/sending-messages-to-a-swing-jtextarea-from-different-places)

I want to use this approach and add the function: writeEntry(String, String) to write to an ArrayList that I can hopefully access from swing; i.e, click 'show' and have it write this list of word pairs to a JText element.

so adding a bit to gustafc's code.

the interface:

```
package com.example.logging;
public interface SimpleActivityLogger {
    void logAction(String message);
    void writeEntry(String s1); //*** I added this ***
}
```

passing it to another class as per gustafc's example:

```
public class SimpleComponentLogger implements SimpleActivityLogger{
    private JTextComponent target;
    private ArrayList data;

    public SimpleComponentLogger(JTextComponent target, ArrayList data){
        this.target = target;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void logAction(final String message){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                target.setText(String.format("%s%s%n", new Object[]{target.getText(), message}));
            }
        });
    }

    public void writeEntry(String s1){
        data.add(s1);
        System.out.println("data array length: " + data.size());
    }
}
```

and then making an implementation:

```
// this originally extended NotesThread, 
// but I assume you won't have that on your system
public class LookupIterator3 extends Thread {
private SimpleActivityLogger logger;

// Constructor that passes logger instance
public LookupIterator3(SimpleActivityLogger logger){
    this.logger = logger;
}

public void doLookup(){
    this.start();
}

public void run()  {
    String[] words = {"the", "quick", "smart", "fox", "jumps", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog"};
    for(int i=0; i<words.length; i++){
        synchronized(words){
        try{
            logger.logAction(words[i]);
            words.wait(500);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ie){ie.printStackTrace();}
        }
        logger.writeEntry(words[i]);
    }
}
}
```

however, when I try to access the ArrayList from swing, it comes back size()=0.
Here's a big chunk of swing, but you should be able to just copy and paste it:

```
public class MySwingTest extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTextField filename = new JTextField();
    private JTextField dir = new JTextField();

    private JTextPane output, answersPane;
    private JScrollPane scroller;
    private SimpleComponentLogger logger;
    private ArrayList answer;

    public MySwingTest() {
  JMenu fileMenu;
  JMenuBar menuBar;
  JMenuItem menuOpen, menuExit;

  JButton answerButton = new JButton("show answers");
  answerButton.addActionListener(new MyListener());

  menuBar = new JMenuBar();
  fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
  menuBar.add(fileMenu);
  menuOpen = new JMenuItem("open file");
  menuExit = new JMenuItem("exit");

  answer = new ArrayList();
  output = new JTextPane();
  logger = new SimpleComponentLogger(output, answer);
  scroller = new JScrollPane(output, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, 
                  JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
  output.setEditable(false);
  answer = new ArrayList();
  answersPane = new JTextPane();
  answersPane.setSize(100, 200);
  answersPane.setEditable(false);

  fileMenu.add(menuOpen);
  fileMenu.add(menuExit);

  menuOpen.addActionListener(new MyListener());
  menuExit.addActionListener(new MyListener());

  JPanel p = new JPanel();
  p.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
  p.add(filename);
  p.add(dir);

  Container cp = getContentPane();
  cp.add(menuBar,BorderLayout.NORTH);
  cp.add(p);
  cp.add(scroller, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  cp.add(answersPane, BorderLayout.WEST);
  cp.add(answerButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

  dir.setEditable(false);
    filename.setEditable(false);
}

// Inner class listener  
class MyListener implements ActionListener {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String eventCommand = e.getActionCommand();
            if(eventCommand.equals("exit")){
                System.exit(0);
            }
            if(eventCommand.equals("show answers")){
                String entry = (String)answer.get(0);
                answersPane.setText(entry);         
            }
            else {
                LookupIterator3 lu3 = new LookupIterator3(logger);
                lu3.doLookup();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        run(new MySwingTest(), 450, 600);
    }

    public static void run(JFrame frame, int width, int height) {
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(width, height);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Sorry about the long question, but this is doing my head in!
Any suggestions?
(I know I'm going to get ragged for writing a long qn, but I don't know what I could have left out)

OK. long edit complete.
Open that baby up and select "open file" from the menu. It will run without a filechooser.

Comment: Hard to say when you don't provide a complete code. What is `answer`? What is `data`? Provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for better help. A wild guess would be that you are not accessing the same instances... but that's just a wild, wild guess.

Comment: What is `answer`? What is `words` used for?  What is `data`? What is the context of your last block of code? I think you've trimmed too much out of your sample.

Comment: When the ArrayList is passed to the constructor it is empty. writeEntry(String, String) writes Japanese English word pairs looked up from a text in a LotusNotes dictionary database. doEntry.toString() writes, and data.size() increments showing the AL is being written to...

Comment: so the TextComponentLogger constructor gets a reference to the ArrayList data = new ArrayList(); right? When TextComponentLogger does writeEntry(String, String), it should write to the original ArrayList data = new ArrayList();, shouldn't it?

Comment: @grooble Stop posting comments and improve your post by adding a complete code. The simple class `TextComponentLogger` does not even compile. Fix those issues so that we can help you.

Comment: OK, TextComponentLogger will compile now. It was missing a closing bracket. Thanks for your feedback, @Guillame Polet, I'll whip up a running version of something that employs the above classes for you to go with. I can't give you the actual implementation as it accesses a Notes DB you won't have access to, but I'll put up something that will describe the problem I'm experiencing. Thanks for keeping this on your radar, and check back in about 16 hrs. Regards.

Comment: @grooble in your TextComponentLogger, there is a reference to a `data` variable but I can't find its declaration anywhere. Try to put complete code so that we can understand what is going on and help you better.

Comment: I'm back at work and I'll have a working example to show you in a bit. The 'data' declaration is the ArrayList declaration between JTextArea and TexComponentArea in the Swing snippet at the very bottom of my code examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is actually quite simple: in your `MySwingTest` constructor you have twice the line :

```
answer = new ArrayList();
```

once before you create your logger and once after. Simply drop the second call and it should work fine.

Note: it is really a bad practice to share ArrayList between your instances (responsability is spread over several classes). It would be a lot simpler if you only had your logger creating directly its own ArrayList and providing access to it with a getter. Even better, it could directly offer an access to the objects it contains (preventing the possibility for other instances to modify the content of the ArrayList).

Note 2: consider using interface-declaration over class-declaration: use `List` instead of `ArrayList` in order to reduce coupling.

Note 3: I would strongly encourage you tu type your collections: `List<String> answer = new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: Gah! 
Thanks for that. It works.
I have tried **a lot** of different ways to get this to work, and all it was, was....
I'll try your suggestion about logger and the getter - that does seem more versatile.
I'll also follow your advice for note 2, however, LotusNotes at work uses java 1.4 so I can't implement note 3. 
Thanks again!