# Creating Swing console with JTextArea and using append text or string (out.println)

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

Creating Swing console with `JTextArea` and using append text or string (`System.out.println`). What is more effective?

I am trying to do console in Swing by using text area. To take string and output to text area with some features like auto completion. What technique would be more effective using append text or strim(System.out.println)? The text area is intended to hold huge amount of entries.

Comment: `strim(System.out.println)`  By `strim` DYM `String` or.. what DYM?

Comment: What you mean by *"using append text or string"*?  `JTextArea` only has `setText` or `appendText` methods

Comment: Sorry its not string I meant strim(System.out.print)

Answer (score 1):

You can look at [Message Console](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/08/message-console/) . I hope this will satisfy your need.

If you wants to use the JTextArea for logging purpose I would suggest to use some logging framework and render the output to the JTextArea or JTextPane. JTextPane will give you flexibility to add the content in different color as well.
My favorite is [Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/). You would have choice to customize them.

You can also choose according to your need. Here is the list of comprehensive logging framework.

[Java Logging Frameworks](http://www.java-logging.com/)

[Wiki of Java Logging framwork](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_logging_framework)

You can also look this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297729/sending-messages-to-a-swing-jtextarea-from-different-places)